# как задать прозрачность HorizontalHeaderItem в pyqt?

Tags: python, pyqt5

[image]

есть таблица, но никак не могу понять как седлать ячейки баланс и аккаунт прозрачными, background-color: rgba пробовал, помогите плиз

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve] и лучше расскажите, что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: я же говорю, мне нужно что бы ячейка "баланс" была прозрачной, но на скриншоте который я прикрепил, эта ячейка белая, и ещё как вы можете заметить на заднем фоне у меня картинка, так вот мне нужно чтобы ячейка "баланс" была прозрачной,и сквозь неё было видно эту картинку, какой мне нужно задать параметр что бы так сделать